# C# AutoCheck Function

Tags: c#, wpf, function

I have a function called `Checking()` to update my UI. I'd like to make this function AutoRun and every 1 Second it runs it and updates my UI.

How can I do that?

Here is my function:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Checking()
}

public void Checking()
{
    if (status= Good)
        UI.color.fill= Green
    else
        UI.color.Fill = Red
}
```

Comment: Why not just bind to the `status` property (or react to a change event)?

Comment: This code does nothing like what you are trying to do.. have you looked at using a Timer, or a Background Worker, etc.. after the Initialize you are calling `Checking()` what are you using to call the Method after the initialize..?

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you

```
//need to add  System.Timers in usings
using System.Timers;

//inside you code
//create timer with interval 2 sec
Timer timer=new Timer(2000);
//add eventhandler 
timer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
//start timer
timer.Start();


private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("324");
        //or other actions
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure the changes made in Checking() are bound and a IPropertyNotifyChange sent for it.

```
using System.Reactive;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Subscribe( _ => Checking() );
}
```

Comment: i think Observable.Interval and System.Reactive are not support by WPF , i cant find the references for them any other similar method??

Comment: @PublicAffair I'm using them today with WPF. You probably just need to add the assembly to the set of project references.

Comment: @PublicAffair if you're not using VS12 yet, it looks like you need to download or nuget it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DispathTimer is timer, that working in one thread with UI. This code  can help you

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(){Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1)};
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Checking();
    }

    public void Checking()
    {   
       .....
    }
```

Comment: The only problem is my Checking() communicating with Serialport! and in a same time other function do the samething so this Auto Function cause my program to crash... im not sure how i can solve this!

Comment: @PublicAffair may be you should synchronize some common data?